# SIM800C-DS power supply schematic

Tags: pcb-design, gsm

I have drawn a circuit diagram of a power supply for a SIM800C-DS IC from the datasheet but is it right or wrong?

I am confused as it's my first time.

I also want to know where to connect the `VDD_EXT` pin.

Powersupply schematic:

[image: Powersupply schematic]

Comment: @JRE - WRT your edit, it is unclear whether the schematic was drawn *for* the OP or *by* the OP themselves... I assumed the former, given the original text, and hence the OP's confusion.

Comment: My understanding was that OP drew it, but had some questions about things that weren't clear.  If I misunderstood, well, OP can tell us and it'll get fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the power supply schematic provided in the datasheet, [SIM800C-DS_Hardware_Design_V1.00](http://www.vis-plus.ee/pdf/SIM800C-DS_Hardware_Design_V1.00.pdf) [Ed. - [new link](https://www.rhydolabz.com/wiki/wp-content/uploads/SIM800C_Hardware_Design_V1.00.pdf), also see below], to which you refer - see section 4.1

[image: Power supply schematic]

So, yes, it would appear that your drawn schematic is correct.

From section 4.1.1

> Pin34 and Pin35 are VBAT input, Pin36 and Pin37 are GND of power supply, and VRTC pin is power supply of
> the RTC circuit in the module. VDD_EXT output 2.8V when module is in normal operation mode.

From section 4.2.1

> Customer can power on SIM800C-DS by pulling down the PWRKEY pin for at least 1 second and release. This
> pin is already pulled up to 3V in the module internal, so external pull up is not necessary. Reference circuits are
> shown as below.

[image: PWRKEY schematic]

Your schematic differs slightly  in this respect. Try building it and see what happens, or ask the person who drew it, why they differed from the PWRKEY in the schematic.

---

**Note**: The datasheet appears to have been updated from v1.00 to V1.05, see [SIM800C_Hardware_Design_V1.05](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM800C/SIM800C_Hardware_Design_V1.05.pdf), and the schematic is now *figure 7* (rather than the previous figure 6) on page 17.

Comment: In the pin connection PWRKEY section , is also correct ?

Comment: Have you actually read the datasheet? I would suggest that you do. I have updated my answer for you. Your schematic differs slightly. Try building it and see what happens. Don't forget to upvote and accept answer, if it helped you.

Comment: Just stumbled over this so sorry for the resurrection. Beginner here. @Greenonline could you tell me the purpose of R103 (470Ohm)? This constantly consumes 8.72mA while the chip takes significantly less in power-savings mode. Seems wasteful in a low power design. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Insa - Please read the datasheet. I have updated the broken links.  If you have a new question, please hit the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can refer back to this answer (and the schematic) for reference by using the URL which is provided by the "share" link under the answer.