# GSM module SIM800C 4V power supply efficiency of circuit

Tags: pcb-design, gsm

This is a follow-up question to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/436720/208059

I (SE not EE) am designing a circuit for a battery-operated IoT node. Power consumption is critical so the GSM module will be in sleep mode 99.5% of the time.

The supply circuit from the [Design Guide Fig.7](https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM800C/SIM800C_Hardware_Design_V1.05.pdf) is all good and well but isn't it wasting a lot of energy in idle? For Vout 4.1V, R103(470 Ohm) is consuming  8.72mA which is ~6x the sleep consumption of the module. I have seen pretty much an identical circuit for another vendor module (quectel.)

What is the purpose of resistor R103 and can it be changed (removed) to minimize energy waste?

[image]

Comment: Is your VOUT only used to power the SIM800C ? If yes you can use the PWR_CTRL to actually switch off the LDO so you have no consumption on R103. (but that would not let it in sleep mode)
If think that R103 is not necessary as in Microchip's datasheet it's not added, that certainly to have a minimum current drawn

Comment: The reason for R103 470E is to fulfill the minimum load current requirement, which is 7mA for your LDO. See chapter 4.3 Minimum Load Current: _"If the output current is too small, leakage currents dominate and the output voltage rises"._

Comment: @Mat thanks for that idea. cutting power altogether is sub-optimal, but might be a backup solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I'm wondering what is the purpose of resistor R103*

If you read the [data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20005685a.pdf) for the MIC29302 you'll see that unloaded, the output voltage can rise above the specifications - the data sheet says that to keep within specifications, the device must have at least 10 mA load current: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That makes total sense. Assuming the module itself draws at least 1.2mA and I could choose a (burstable) MIC2915x and factor in the min module load. I could get away with 5mA in total, right? Would you rather recommend getting a fixed 4V LDO 
 for this scenario somehow? I know, they are not that common.

Comment: You can get adjustable and very low current LDO regulators from Microchip @Insa

Comment: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/products/power-management/dc-dc-converters-and-voltage-regulators/linear-ldo-voltage-regulators/low-quiescent-current-ldo-regulators#

Comment: thanks I will investigate further. Thing is the module does tx bursts at 2A for 577us and dropout cannot be more that 350mA, which probably narrows down the choices there.

Comment: Add more bulk capacitance to the output to soak up the 2 amp surge taken by the load is my advice.